# Can I use a steam controller with Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Is it possible to get a Steam Controller to work with Overwatch?  I'd like to map the right touchpad to mouse movement if possible.

Comment: dont know if its possible, but why would you like to do that? mouse has a lot more sensitivity imo. i hate using a controller for anything besides racing or sports games

Comment: @Dragonrage I have friends who prefer controllers to KB + M and I don't feel like being 'that guy' lecturing them on KB + M response time.

Comment: oh, well I feel sorry for them. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's fully compatible with Steam Controllers. You'll be at a slight disadvantage against keyboard/mice players, but it should still work fine.

Here's an example of a player using the Steam Controller to play Overwatch. Appropriate buttons can be mapped in the Controls settings.

To actually get Overwatch compatible with the Steam Controller, it must be run through Steam, so:

1. Select the option `Games` -> `Add a Non-Steam Game to my Library`
2. Add Overwatch.exe to your library.
   [image]
3. Launch Overwatch through Steam.

Note that this will also cause you to have two clients running, both Steam, and Battle.net, so you may want to avoid setting up a controller if you have issues running both clients at the same time.

This is just an overview,  but [reddit user /u/malecden has a very good setup tutorial listed here on reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3tfrv5/guide_how_to_use_steam_overlay_with_the_blizzard/) in order to get the Steam Controller functionality to work with OW.